# How to pass the 'pressed' mouse event to another object which is created only after 'press' event triggered

Tags: qt, qml

By setting 'propagateComposedEvents' to true, able to pass the mouse event to already present underneath mouse area. But is there a way that if we click on RectA mouse area then RectB is created from that point under RectA and pass the 'pressed' mouse event to RectB.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow{
    id: applWindow
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300
    x:100
    y:100
    

    Loader{
        id: loader
    }

    Component{
        id: rectBComponent
        Rectangle{
            id:rectB
            color:"green"
            width: 50
            height: 50
            z: -1  // to create rectB below the rectA

            Component.onCompleted:{console.log("rectB created")}

            MouseArea{
                id:rectBMouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed:console.log("rect B recevied press event") // handler to receive the press event
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id:rectA
        color:"red"
        width: 50
        height: 50

        MouseArea{
            id: rectAMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            propagateComposedEvents: true
            onPressed:{
                console.log("mouse clicked on rectA")
                loader.sourceComponent = rectBComponent // create rectB when rectA is pressed
                if(loader.status == Loader.Ready)
                {
                    loader.item.x = rectA.x
                    loader.item.y = rectA.y
                    loader.item.width = rectA.width
                    loader.item.height = rectA.height
                    console.log("passing the mouse event")
                    mouse.accepted = false // not accept mouse event and pass it to below object
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please clarify that can I pass the mouse event to another object which is created after the mouse event is triggered.

Comment: Are you sure the new object is created in time?

Comment: The Event is already passed !! Your question not clear ? do you want rect b only to receive the event ??

Comment: @JarMan,Yes, the new object is created on time. To confirm this i have added a print message and object created message is printing first and then printing the 'passing mousing event' message.

Comment: @MohammadKanan, yes I want rectB to receive the mouse event when clicked on rectA. But at the point when I click on rectA, rectB was not created at all.

Comment: @MohankumarChar , recB is surely created , receives focus and events logs clicks, looks like you have another issue specific how you run your app. The code as above does create rectB and it receives events.

Comment: @MohammadKanan, rectB doesn't receive mouse press event on the first click even though it gets created. But rectB starts to receive events from the second time onwards and i think that is because its already present under the rectA after the first press event.

Comment: @MohankumarChar , naturedly it won't until its created , you can connect to signal from rectA to handle the press

Comment: @MohammadKanan, but rectB is creating first and then we setting 'mouse.accepted = false', isn't it?. I need the press event itself to be passed to rectB in order to create a drag event. So by using connections, I can see when mouse press event triggered on rectA, but programmatically i can't emit mouse 'pressed' signal on rectB.